# WebSphere AS active/passive cluster

Tags: websphere

I have an EAR and I am deploying it in a WAS cluster. WAS version is 7. I want this to be an Active/Passive cluster.

I am wondering how can I make sure that only one node is started at a time? And how to instuct WAS to start up the second node in case the first one crashes?

Comment: as an alternative, why not let all the cluster servers remain active, but configure your HTTP server to only use one and fall back to the others once the initial server is downed?

Comment: Because the HTTP is not the only activity the JVM may have. For instance, I'm using JMS communication as well.

Comment: I guess I'm just concerned about the lag between the detection of the downed server and the time it takes to bring up another. it makes fail overs "less" seamless. still, to each their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such topology in WAS.

There is way to create backup Cell. 
If main cell is crushed, backup cell will be active.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to control the entire "node" as described, but you can insure that only one "Server" (aka JVM) is running for the cluster.

1. Expand Server > expand Clusters > click, Dynamic clusters > click on [your cluster]
2. A few sections down on this config page you'll see the section, **Maximum number of cluster instances**

   A.  Select, "Limit the number of instances that can start" and fill in "1".

Also make sure that your cluster membership policy includes multiple nodes (you can verify this by clicking "preview membership".)

Comment: Are the Dynamic Clusters part of WebSphere AS 7? It is a special version of WAS? Looks like it's part of WebSphere Virtual Enterprise

Comment: Sorry, but it appears you are correct, WVE is required for dynamic clusters on WAS 7.0.  

If both are in "WebSphere application server cluster" then you could manipulate weights to 20 for the primary and 1 for passive, but it would still get a small % of requests.  Setting the "passive" server to 0 should idle it, but you would have to verify it would handle requests when the active goes down.